# Streamlit: python scripts are displayed in the menu. How to hide a script from Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have 3 Python scripts to use as pages on Streamlit. Other script is not a page, but you can see it in the menu. Please, how can I hide this script?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWyjL.png)

I haven't imported Streamlit library to it.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you move the Python file to be outside of the `pages` folder, it won't appear in the sidebar